# Equivalent of IDA FLIRT signatures for GDB?

Tags: gdb, flirt-signatures

Are there equivalent tools/procedures to IDA's FLIRT signatures, when working on statically linked binaries, with other disassemblers?

Is it at all possible with GDB/objdump?

Comment: Well, the DWARF format is open, you could always write code that generates or transforms existing information. Given FLIRT as an example I assume that you have such information.

Comment: I mentioned FLIRT, as it is the only thing i know about (regarding this specific topic).

Comment: May be merge with this one? https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13345/open-source-equivalent-for-flirt/13347

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if other tools offer the same functionality, but if you have IDA, you can do File->Produce File->Create MAP File to create a .MAP file with the names that IDA determined (or which were manually created by the user).  Many other debugging tools have the ability to load .MAP files, so I have used this trick for example with SoftICE and OllyDbg.